# Scrolling to top after collapsible click

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I use material css collapsible. I want to scroll to top whenever any of the item is expanded or closed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapsible-header').click(function (e) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: can  you create a working code including HTML/CSS and JS so we can test ?

Comment: Have you tried to make the html <a href>? Which will scroll to '#top'? If you understand what i mean..

Comment: I guess you have selector issue where you want to listen any click event is triggered. Try using a `console.log()` into the click event to check whether it is triggering or not. Better to put some html code to visualize more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

you must use options like this:

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible({
    onOpen: function(el) { $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); }, // Callback for Collapsible open
    onClose: function(el) { $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); } // Callback for Collapsible close
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

.Scrolltop() function is available in jQuery

Please refer to the jQuery documentation related to scrolltop
https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: That doesnt work, just try that when implementing in material